# Trying to re format y label from10000 to 10,000 , and get this : set_ticks() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ticks'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to re format y label , my code is

```
ax.set_xticks(x[::12])
ax.set_xticklabels(x[::12],rotation = -45)
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(val)for val in ax.set_yticks()])

ax.axvline(x=24,linewidth=1,color='k',label='Low',linestyle='--')
ax.axvline(x=96,linewidth=1,color='k',label='High',linestyle='--')

ax.axvspan(24,96,ymin=0,ymax = 300,facecolor='k',alpha=0.1)
ax.legend(loc=1)



fig.set_size_inches(16,12)
fig.suptitle("Time Series Plot of Temperature",fontsize='18',fontname='Times New Roman')
fig.savefig('lineplot.jpg',dpi=600)
```

and I got this Error:

```
TypeError: set_ticks() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ticks'
```

Does anyone know how ti fix it ?

Comment: You're not calling `set_ticks`. PLease add the full traceback so we can see where it's being called in your code.

Comment: Maybe you'd want to replace `... for val in ax.set_yticks()])` with `...for val in ax.get_yticks()])`?

Comment: you don't want to use `set_yticks` or `set_yticklabels` here. You want to `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
ax.set_xticklabels(indexs, rotation=90)
```